# Create JSON array by each-loop through parent and child elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, each

**HTML:**

```
<section id="intro">
        <div id="ih" contenteditable="true">Header</div>
        <div id="ish" contenteditable="true">Subheader</div>
        <a id="ibtn" contenteditable="true">Test</a>
</section>

<section id="articles">
        <div id="ah" contenteditable="true">Header</div>
        <div id="ash" contenteditable="true">Subheader</div>
        <a id="btn-1" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
        <a id="btn-2" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
        <a id="btn-3" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
</section>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-button').click(function() {
        var dataObj = [];
        var jsonObj = [];
        $('section').each(function() {
            var section = $(this).attr('id');
            if( $(this).find('[contenteditable]').length != 0 ) {
                $('[contenteditable=true]').each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    dataObj.push('\"' + id + '\":\"' + $(this).html() + '\"');
                });
                jsonObj.push('{\"' + section + '\":{' + dataObj + '}}');
                dataObj.length = 0;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
        alert(jsonObj);
    });
});
```

**Goal:**

Create an JSON array(?) which contains the `section` name followed by a set of `elementID+html` if any of the sections children contains the attribute `contenteditable` and that attribute is set to `true`.

Currently it's including it's not ending the `jsonObj` as it should, it includes the second `section` into that array as well and for the second `section` includes the first `sections` data.

I've tried to empty the dataObj array using `dataObj.length = 0;` without success.

What am I doing wrong?

**Final goal:**

Create a inline editor connected to a Laravel 5.1 back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like Rejith's answer, I would recommend this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-button').click(function() {
        var jsonObj = {};
        $('section').each(function() {
            var section = {};

            $(this).find('[contenteditable="true"]').each(function() {
                section[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).html();
            });

            jsonObj[$(this).attr('id')] = section;
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    });
});
```

You don't need to build a JSON object form the start, you can build a regular object then convert it to the JSON notation.

Comment: Added my if-statement to not include sections in the JSON object doesn't contain elements with contenteditable attribute. After that, this solution works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to get?

```js
var objectMain = {};
$('section').each(function() {
  var section = $(this).attr('id');
  objectMain[section] = {};
  if ($(this).find('[contenteditable]').length != 0) {
    $('[contenteditable=true]').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      objectMain[section][id] = $(this).html();
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
console.log(objectMain);
$('#stringJ').html(JSON.stringify(objectMain))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intro">
  <div id="ih" contenteditable="true">Header</div>
  <div id="ish" contenteditable="true">Subheader</div>
  <a id="ibtn" contenteditable="true">Test</a>
</section>

<section id="articles">
  <div id="ah" contenteditable="true">Header</div>
  <div id="ash" contenteditable="true">Subheader</div>
  <a id="btn-1" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
  <a id="btn-2" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
  <a id="btn-3" contenteditable="true">Button</a>
</section><br/><br/>
<div id="stringJ" ></div>
```

Comment: Tried this but got the same result as before, I'm sorry but it might just be because I'm so new to jQuery/JSON. Thank you for your help.